# python: parsing data from a buffer

Tags: python, json, parsing, pycurl

I collect data from a website, using the pycurl functions. Following the example code, after slight modifications I do get all the data in one big buffer. It comes in a format of { "field_id":"data","field_id2":"data2", .. } I wish to parse this into lines of text, similar to csv, with one line of output for each set of data enclosed by curly braces. How best to achieve this, as "pythonic" as can be? Oh, and where can I best do the UTF-8 conversion? I suspect the source coding to be ISO8859 - but that is a secondary matter.

Relevant code:

```
buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, MY_URL)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()
```

Sample data:

```
`{"status":"ok","nature":"Liste des champs principaux de tous les terrains publi\u00e9s","count":"1211","liste":
 [{"id":"3667","date_modif":"2013-04-03 11:27:00","code_terrain":"LF5155","toponyme":"Champagne Vol Libre","type_terrain":"Base ULM Autorisation OBLIGATOIRE ","latitude":"N 48 56 10","longitude":"E 004 03 42","altitude":"335` ft","pays":"France","region":"Grand-Est","departement":"Marne","ville":"Villeneuve"},
{"id":"5118","date_modif":"2015-08-18 13:17:23","code_terrain":"LF4861","toponyme":"La Canourgue Conques","type_terrain":"A\u00e9rodrome ferm\u00e9.","latitude":"N 44 24 55","longitude":"E 003 17 05","altitude":"2920 ft","pays":"France","region":"Occitanie","departement":"Loz\u00e8re","ville":"La Canourgue"}
```

Comment: Thanks, PRMoureu but that doesn't work. Perhaps I am missing something elementary, as already said JSON is new terrain for me. The error is "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: how did you get the sample output ? you could use the same way with `json.loads(result_string)`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse a JSON file, maybe will be useful to look at the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Ah! I had never yet come across JSON formatted data, that's why I didn't recognise the format.

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" my answer so also other people coming to here will find the solution and will "trust" it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
result = json.loads('{"something": 1}', encoding="ISO8859")  # default encoding is utf-8
print(result["something"])

>>> 1
```

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the problem, it is always better if you can explain why your answer solves the question.  This helps when others view the answer to understand what has changed and why it should be done this way.